# I want to change the checkbox icons in ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4, ionicons, ion-checkbox

I want to use my own icon for the ionic  checkbox (ion-checkbox). I manage to do it in the console by changing the class of a div that I don't have in my html sheet..

My code :

```
` <ion-col col-4  class="left ">
      <ion-item class="noBorder modFilter" >
        <ion-label></ion-label>
        <ion-checkbox (click)="launchSearch()"[(ngModel)]="housing">
        </ion-checkbox>`
```

The code in the console :

```
  ` <ion-checkbox class="checkbox checkbox-ios ng-untouched ng- 
   pristine 
       ng-valid" ng-reflect-model="false">
  <div class="checkbox-icon">
  <div class="checkbox-inner"></div> 
  </div>`
```

If i change div class="checkbox-inner" by div class="my-custom-icon" in the console, it's good but i don't know how can i do that, because i don't see this div..

Help me please, if you have any idea ..

Comment: which icon do you want to change?

Comment: the checkbox-icon

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37216043/ionic-ion-checkbox-can-we-change-icon-with-another-icon

Comment: and try third party component like https://github.com/lokesh-coder/pretty-checkbox

Comment: Thanks, i'm trying that. I Make you a return !